# Dynamically passing URL

Tags: 2013, url

I have a SharePoint 2013 list, here am retrieving attachments url of each record using SPServices and dynamically passing it in  a table. But my URL is breaking up if it contains special characters. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
$("<td valign='top'> <a href="+attachmentsURL+">URL</a></td>").addClass("projectTest").appendTo(row);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The special characters should be encoded.

Try `encodeURI(attachmentsURL)`.